# Rollup bundles correctly but Vue is undefined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, rollup

I'm using rollup to bundle with vue and typescript. I'm getting the following errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'Vue' of undefined
Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
```

I understand this has something to do with Vue not loading correctly. I do have Vue above my script file. So I'm not sure why this is happening. Any ideas?

Here's my files:

// index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <title>View</title>
  <link href="~/vuecss/styles.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="~/vuejs/vendors.min.js"></script>
  <script src="~/vuejs/app.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

// app.ts

```
import Vue from "vue";
import HelloComponent from "./hello/hello.vue";

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    HelloComponent
  }
});
```

// hello.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="name" type="text">
    <div>{{name}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import Vue from "vue";

  export default Vue.extend({
    data: { name: "World" }
  });
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
  body {
    background: #303030;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #fff;
    line-height: 1.5;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }
</style>
```

//rollup.config.vendors.js (bundles vuejs)

```
export default {
  entry: 'node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js',
  dest: 'vuejs/vendors.min.js',
  format: 'iife'
}
```

//rollup.config.js (bundles ts and vue scripts)

```
import rollupTS from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2'
import rollupVue from 'rollup-plugin-vue'
import rollupSCSS from 'rollup-plugin-scss'
import rollupUglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify'

export default {
  entry: 'vuesrc/app.ts',
  dest: 'vuejs/app.min.js',
  format: 'iife',

  plugins: [
    rollupTS(),
    rollupVue({
      autoStyles: false,
      styleToImports: true,
      compileTemplate: true
    }),
    rollupSCSS({
      output: 'vuecss/styles.min.css',
      outputStyle: 'compressed'
    }),
    rollupUglify()
  ]
}
```

File structure screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/GNZ8tvpvy 
Vue is working but still shows the error: https://www.screencast.com/t/6dY52k2n

EDIT: Added a CDN and got this error from view:

[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. It wasn't working when I ran vue through rollup to just move the file, rename it, and output it via this code:

//rollup.config.vendors.js (bundles vuejs)

```
export default {
  entry: 'node_modules/vue/dist/vue.min.js',
  dest: 'vuejs/vendors.min.js',
  format: 'iife'
}
```